# qt6 designer in python

Tags: python, pyqt6

i was unable to open my pyqt designer and after digging around a little I found that you can use
`qt6-tools designer` instead of `pyqt6designer`
my question is if there is a way to change the command so non working one will do the same as the working one

Comment: Do you mean that you have two versions of PyQt Designer installed? What do you mean when you say you are unable to open pyqt designer? Were you not able to find it or did you click on a link that didn't work? Which command are you asking about changing?

Comment: from all the guides I found all of them use ```pyqt6designer``` to launch the designer I need to use ```qt6-tools designer``` in console to launch it and it causes trouble down the line... I'm asking if I can change the command somehow